# Also get the first level value with Nested Object Destructuring

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

I'm looking for the best way retrieve some nested attributes as variables but also the outer object as a variable.

In this example `wheels` is undefined, but I need it for later use.

```js
const bike = { wheels: { front:"big", rear:"small" } }; 

const { wheels : { front } } = bike;
console.log(typeof wheels === "undefined"); // true
console.log(front);
```

Meanwhile I solved it this way:

```js
const bike = { wheels: { front:"big", rear:"small" } }; 

const { wheels, wheels : { front } } = bike;
console.log(typeof wheels === "undefined"); // false
console.log(front);
```

But it feels like boilerplate... I couldn't find any smarter solution. Am I missing something or is there no other, simpler way?

Comment: You aren't missing anything. If that is "boilerplate" for you, try to write the same in Java ;)

Comment: By destructuring there's no other way !!!

Comment: Okay so I will live with it, thanks for your answers!